# Chart.js. Edit bar width -v2.5-

Tags: chart.js

I am having to give some symmetry to two charts. There is a big space under the chart at right I want to get rid of.
[image]

Probably is an easy to change parameter of yAxis in config, but I am quite lost. I don't find anything in official docs or web. 
I've already tried with Barwidth, categorySpacing, barPercentage, etc

Real example at : https://jsfiddle.net/j1dffbgk/

```
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why that space is appearing, is because, you have an empty label in your `labels` array.

```
labels: [
   ["aaa", ' ff'],
   ["aa", " ddd"], "ee eeee", ""
                              ^^
],
```

Remove that empty label *(if not necessary)* and you will be good to go.

Here is the **[working code on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xkhe47y/)**

Comment: Great!!!  I was pulling my hear with such a silly mistake  .  :D
I've learnt a lot about chart.js anyway.

Thank you!!